# Android - Listview - setOnItemClickListener doesnt work

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, adapter

I've implemented a Listview which contain a picture and a text.

It works fine , I can select an item and the selected item's background color changes to the Selector's color.. but the OnItemClick listener doesnt fire!

I set my list's setOnItemClickListener.

Iv'e read about focusable, clickable etc.. didnt help me.

I set all the listview items' focusable and clickable to false, then tried on the layout containing the items

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

still nothing seems to help.
What freaks me out that the selector indication works. Any help?

Edit: The Listview is inside a popup if it matters.

Comment: Can you post some of the code which you are using? Debugging is much easier when you can see the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PopupWindows are not focusable by default.

It may effect the Listviews to give false-positive , but if their container is not focused - they wont function normally. just set the popup's focusable attribute to true before showing it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set `android:clickable="true"` in parentlayout of AdapterView, remove it.